# Problems when building VS Code on Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I tried to build [VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode) on Linux through yarn like

```
cd vscode
yarn
```

but it show

```
Package x11 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `x11.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'x11' found
Package xkbfile was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xkbfile.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xkbfile' found
```

I had had libX11.dev , libxkbfile.dev and libsecret-1-dev installed using

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxkbfile-dev
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-dev
```

and add the path to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable in /etc/profile,but it still doesn't work.
Any other dependencies mentioned in [Contributing to Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run) are already installed and availble.
Besides,I had tried both on CentOS 7,CentOS 8 and Ubuntu 18.04,but they had problems almost the same.

Comment: I think you already have the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878536/no-package-xkbfile-found-when-build-vscode-on-ubuntu

Comment: The answer above installed many packages using ```sudo apt-get install -y g++ gcc make python2.7 pkg-config libx11-dev libxkbfile-dev``` but all these packages have been installed before on my computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No package 'xkbfile' found when build vscode on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878536/no-package-xkbfile-found-when-build-vscode-on-ubuntu)